# Where can I see partitions I divided during installation?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I created two partitions of 500GB HDD and installed Ubuntu 12.04 on one of it.....

Where can I find the other partition that is not used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Disk Utility. There you can view, delete, mount, and format partitions. You can also get information about your hard drives.

Answer (score 2):

Install the `gparted` package. One way to do this is in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Then run GParted, and you will see your partitions.

Comment: If you asked the additional partition to be formatted, you will be able to see it in the Places panel, on the upper left. Clicking there will bring up the empty "root" folder on that partition to which you can copy files. If you didn't format it you can use gparted to format it (just be careful which one you choose, formatting erases all the data on a partition).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to see partitions, I think you should run the `palimpsest` tool. It should be somewhere in system settings, and you need the `gnome-disk-utility` package (should be installed by default).

Then you will see your partition, format them, etc. Be careful before touching disks with that of course.